# JGiven integration for Quarkus testing

Tags: java

I want to add JGiven capabilities to my Quarkus tests that use the `@QuarkusTest`  annotation (and hence the underlying `QuarkusTestExtension` junit extension).  The the `jgiven-spring-junit5` library lets use JGiven with Spring application tests by combining the `SpringExtension` and `JGivivenExtension` classes.

My searches have discovered nothing off-the-shelf to do this or any eamples of anyone integration JGiven and Quarkus.  Time restraints don't allow me to study the internals of Quarkus' injection framework and develop my own integration.  Has anyone successfully achieved this?